# Mysql - Select user by items related to him

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: tbl_users and tbl_users_jobs.

tbl_users as the use information
tbl_users_jobs as jobs, that are related to that user.

Let's say I have 3 users: id 1, 2 and 3.

User 1 has 2 jobs, user 3 has 3 jobs and user 2 has 1 job only.
I want to insert a new job to the user who has less jobs (So I can distribute jobs to all users).

How would I do that?
Need consider one thing too: 
A user may start today for example and has no jobs...

Here's the table structure:

```
tbl_user
-------
Id
name
```

-

```
tbl_users_jobs
-------
Id
user_id
description
```

Thanks.

Comment: How do you keep track of the assigned jobs?

Comment: The only relation between job and users is the user_id on tbl_users_jobs

Comment: Isn't better to add a filed to tbl_user (for example assigned_jobs) to keep track of them? Otherwise I think you have to use `COUNT` and I don't think it is good for performance, but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: I've tought about that, but then I would have to track all place that I insert a job to that user and update the track, and Might be a problem, cause the job can be "paused" or removed for example, maybe its gonna be too much work. I don' mind use COUNT cause it won't have much access and the server can handle thousands ..

Comment: @StiveKnx, I do agree with Dheed ... best way would be having a `int` field in your `tbl_user` table where you can store the no.of jobs per user then while querying you can save the cost of joins and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count jobs per user (including new users who don't have jobs) with a `LEFT JOIN`.

The trick is to count on a column in `tbl_users_jobs` because the column's value will be null for new users and will return a zero count. Just be sure to count a column that can't otherwise be null; in this case I've chosen `tbl_users_jobs.Id` under the assumption that it's the PK:

```
SELECT
  tbl_user.Id,
  tbl_user.Name,
  COUNT(tbl_users_jobs.Id) AS JobCount
FROM tbl_user
LEFT JOIN tbl_users_jobs ON tbl_user.Id = tbl_users_jobs.user_id
GROUP BY
  tbl_user.Id,
  tbl_user.Name
ORDER BY JobCount DESC
```

Results are returned in order of who has the fewest jobs. You can take the first row as your user to get the new job, but keep in mind that there may be other users with the same number of jobs - in other words there may be 2 or 3 or more users with zero jobs. You'll have to decide how to choose between them.

Comment: I'm just asking: is it a good practice to count the rows for every user? Isn't better to use a field inside `tbl_user` that keeps track of the assigned jobs?

Comment: If I use LIMIT it will return just one, right? And the one with less jobs (even if has 0). I think the important part would be just choose an user to the job and don't let just one person has all of them ..

Comment: Counting is good practice because it keeps the database normalized. If you keep a field inside `tbl_user` then it would always have to match with the number of rows in `tbl_users_jobs`, and it's difficult to keep them in sync. You could say "I'll keep them in sync" but if you're on a team project and you're not using normalized design I can guarantee you - sooner or later it'll get out of sync :)

Comment: StiveKnx - yes, `LIMIT 1` will give you just one row. I disn't recommend that because I wasn't sure what you want to do when there's a tie for "least number of jobs". If you don't have a tie-breaker in mind then yes, go ahead with `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Well I decided to use this query using LIMIT 1 at the end ... All Users are getting jobs, no one is staying without and no one has a lot (my intention). Thanks.

Comment: @EdGibbs I'm asking because I'm doing something similar(and it looks like it works): when someone open a ticket I search for the operator with a one line query and then when I update the ticket information the operator's assigned tickets increase, almost the same happens when someone close the ticket :)

Comment: I agree with @EdGibbs Eve with me happens that I don't update the value all the time, and I work with another people, I don't think is gonna to be the best idea ...